# Printing entire line, should one substring of line match condition

Tags: java, arraylist

So using the following code:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Program10.txt")))
{
String sCurrentLine;
String[] splits;
            
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
splits = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
}
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(splits); // prints as null
```

I've read the file, Program10.txt, by line to get:

```
[1000  31000  3 Texas, 
1042  12180.06  3 Texas, 
1062  13240.45  2 Texas, 
1200  36000  2 Maryland, 
1327  19800.56  2 Alaska, 
1483  22458.23  7 Texas, ...
]
```

And I'm hoping to print the entire line when the income (so the second element is greater than average income, which is 5,037) with the following code (***I suspect the problem is with the bolded code):

```
ArrayList<Household> households = new ArrayList<Household>();
**// This will create new household object
Household household = new Household(
Integer.parseInt(splits[0]), 
Double.parseDouble(splits[1]), 
Integer.parseInt(splits[2]), 
splits[3]);
```

I'm getting a null Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Program10.readFile(Program10.java:129)
**(line 129 corresponds to the code "Integer.parseInt(splits[0]), "**

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: You're throwing out every single array placed into the splits array except the last one, and I don't think that this is what you really want to be doing.

Comment: Why not instead print each array ***inside*** the while loop, right after creating each array?

Comment: hmmm I'm still getting an error when I place the Integer.parseInt(splits[0]),
              Double.parseDouble(splits[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(splits[2]) inside that while loop. What do you mean by throwing out the array?

Comment: Say, that you're reading 10 lines, as the while loop loops, you assign to splits a new array, and discard the previous *without doing anything with it*, without printing it, storing it, nothing. Only the last array entered is the one that is eventually printed. Again, I don't think that this is what you want to do since it simply makes no sense at all. As for your null issue -- time to fire up your debugger to see what is null, when and then why.